# Vamos converter a tag "conversão" em algo útil?

Tags: debate, tags

A *tag* [conversão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convers%c3%a3o) parece ser na verdade [conversão-de-tipos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convers%c3%a3o-de-tipos) na maior parte do tempo, mas não tudo. Vamos verificar quase devem mudar para a segunda, ou mudar para alguma coisa e quais só devem perder essa *tag* se ela não ajudar classificar nada?

Ou alguém acha que ela assim deveria existir? Me parece genérica demais, ou coloca algo mais específico e ou não precisa dela.

Se tiver dúvida, pergunte antes de mudar algo.

Quem quiser ajudar avise, para não haver duplicidade de esforços.

Comment: +1 pela piadinha

Comment: A tag `conversão` é muito ampla, então eu creio que deveria ser descartada

Comment: @riki481 a proposta é justamente esta.

Answer (score 5):

A tag de [conversão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convers%c3%a3o) pode se referir a conversão de tipos de dados, bases decimais, estruturas, etc. No entanto, ela está abrangendo tudo de forma geral e isso é errado. Tags devem ser específicas ao uso e não genéricas (como supramencionado).

Senão, faria sentido ter uma tag [programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o) afinal.

Também vejo em perguntas a utilização de duas tags para suprir a [conversão-de-tipos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convers%c3%a3o-de-tipos), no qual usam [conversão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convers%c3%a3o) e [tipagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tipagem) simultaneamente. Acredito que o ideal é usar a primeira tag citada neste parágrafo.

Também acredito que a remoção da tag [conversão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convers%c3%a3o) já iria resolver ambos destes problemas, porque seria mandatório especificar que tipo de conversão o usuário aponta.

Em contra-partida à solução acima, vejo que alguns usuários com reputação insuficiente para criar uma tag apropriada (como a [conversão-de-bases](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convers%c3%a3o-de-bases)), no entanto usam a tag [conversão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convers%c3%a3o) para categorizar suas perguntas. De certa forma, não estão errados.